# I cant download wine on 11.10

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, update-manager

Im brand new to Linux in general, ive only been using it a few days, and I keep getting a huge amount of 404 errors when running `sudo apt-get update` here are some examples

`Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/universe i386 Packages         404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en                       Err http://security.ubuntu.com oneiric-security/multiverse i386 Packages       404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]`

that then gives me failed to fetch errors like this

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
```

Im using ubuntu 11.10 ( the reason im running on an old version is because im using amd legacy drivers)

Comment: This version of Ubuntu has reached eol and is off-topic here. (As it is no longer supported it no longer gets security updates)

Comment: Why would you download a version from 2011? Of course you can't run `apt-get update`; those PPAs have been inactive for four years.

Comment: im running such an old version because im using a legacy driver for my gpu and i need an earlier version of xserver

Comment: 11.10 is too old. You really won't be able to do much and you are ***very*** vulnerable to security holes. Are you sure a newer Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE won't work?

Comment: i really dont know, like i said im brand new, i literally just started using linux on friday, and this was the only one i found with an old enough version of xserver

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the index for that repo and look at the distributions, I think you are going to find that oneiric is no longer supported due to its age.

Try opening up this link in a browser and review the distro names supported:
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/

Hope that clarifies it for you!  As for legacy drivers, you might want to get a new question opened up to figure out how to get your older hardware working on newer versions of Ubuntu.  Most of the legacy drivers, from what I understand, are incorporated into the kernel now.  With the exception of PAE, which a google search should help find solutions to install Ubuntu and other Linux distros on a non-PAE processor.  I had that problem myself.

I haven't tried this myself, but you might try disabling that repo in your sources so it still tries to download wine, since that is what you are actually trying to download.  Otherwise you might just read up on how to download wine via source and make/compile it yourself.  It's a solid read, but not terribly difficult if you follow along the directions.

Either way, good luck!